# Difference between branches $[-\pi, \pi)$ and $[\pi, 3\pi)$ of the complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I think that both branches just exclude the negative part of the real line. So what's the difference between them then?

Comment: The difference is $2\pi i $.

Comment: Can you please clarify? When we go from $\pi$ and make half-round counterclockwise, we pass $2\pi$, and then another half-round is at $3\pi$. Likewise, when we go from $-\pi$, we make a full round and stop at the same point. So, then, I don't see the difference.

Comment: $\log z = \log |z| + i \arg z$, so it makes a difference if the argument is in $[-\pi, \pi)$ or in $[\pi, 3\pi)$. Perhaps you can clarify the question.

Comment: When we want to exclude the negative portion of the real line, do the arguments in $[-\pi, \pi)$ and $[\pi, 3\pi)$ work equally well for this purpose?

Comment: The same part of the complex plane is covered but the logarithm is increased by $2\pi i$. This is important when you add terms like $\log(x^m)$ instead of $m\log(x)$ for $x\gg 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in \mathbf{R}$, the numbers $x$ and $x+2\pi$ can be said to represent the same *angle*, but they are still different *numbers*. So when computing the logarithm of a given complex number using the two branches you describe, you obtain two different complex numbers (which differ by $2\pi i$).